# How can I make this menu centered and bordered, while still working when resized by the browser?

Tags: html, css

So I've got this horizontal menu bar centered on a page, completely styled with CSS, and whenever one zooms in or out, the border will either get wider than the contained elements or force the last element to go down to the next line. How can I change this so it works fine when the browser zooms?

The relevant html file can be found at http://fullforcespiritwear.com/example.html and the css is http://fullforcespiritwear.com/ex.css.

Answer (score 0):

Give width to your `<body>` or an outer container and use percentage value for `<ul>` width instead of fixed width.

```
body {
background-color:black;
width:1015px;
}
#nav {
border:2px solid #FF0000;
display:block;
height:37px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Both problems still happen when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are quick compromise settlement: remove hard width in px from a and add fluid width in percents to li: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pereskokov/eMPCD/.

**Edit:** New, sweet and cool version: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pereskokov/eMPCD/1/

Comment: Nice! That completely solves the problem when zooming in, however there are still some artifacts when zooming out. You can see on the jsfiddle that if you zoom out, the red border of #nav exceeds the combined width of the elements, and a lot of black background shines through.

Comment: I think that there are no soluitions in pure css, because when you zooming, you width in pixels becomes a float, not integer. There are another solution — remove red border from ul, and add this border to li: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pereskokov/eMPCD/1/